# How to add items to a listbox from a different form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listbox, multiple-forms

I am trying to add a new item to a listbox in form1 from form2. The idea behind it is to end up with a list of different items each being different from each other (or the same, doesnt matter) based on the form2 activity. Say I open form1 (and it has shopping list (listbox))and I open form2 and click button which would add "bannana" to the list in form1. How do I do this? I've tryed various ways such as adding "addToList(parameter)" method in the form1 and then calling it from form2 and passing parameters but the list would remain empty however other things such as message box would pop up etc. So any ideas how to solve this?

I am using this method in form one to add the items into the list and it works:

```
public void addToList()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Adding stuff to list");
    listEvent.Items.Add("New item 1");
    listEvent.Items.Add("new item 2");
    MessageBox.Show("Done adding");
    listEvent.Refresh();
}
```

Now when I try to call it from another class/form I use this:

```
public void changeForm()
{
    EventPlanner mainEventForm = new EventPlanner();
    mainEventForm.addToList();
}
```

Or:

```
private void btnAddEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EventPlanner mainEventForm = new EventPlanner();
    mainEventForm.addToList();
}
```

But it still doesnt work. Although when I use it from form1 (eventplanner, where the list is) it works perfectly fine. I even changed access modifyer to public so that shouldnt be the problem.

Comment: What's the idea of using two forms for this ? Why can't you make it in one form ?

Comment: I am trying to make a nice and neat interface and the second form will varry from the options selected say you choose blue or green and depending on that the new form will have blue (or green) elements etc. (if you get the idea).

Comment: The code that you have posted does not work because you are creating a new instance of your EventPlanner form instead of using the already existing instance.

Comment: How do I use the already existing one? Im not very advanced programmer so I ahve only basics covered. Help is much apretiated :)

Comment: You will be better off using events or creating a public property on form2. Use show dialog to show form2 then use the dialog result to determine wether or not to read the property with the information you which to add to the list.

Comment: What about `NameOfMainForm.AddToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a public Method on Form2 as I mentioned in my comment to your question. Here is a simple example.

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        if (frm2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(frm2.getItem());
        }
        frm2.Close();
        frm2.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**From2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        button2.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    public string getItem()
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```