# Why does my form still add an item to the list when it is closed?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

So far, I have a form1 where I press a button, it will load up a second form which has a couple of textboxes and a combobox to be filled in by the user which will then be added a to a list displayed in a listview on the form1. However, it works fine except when i close the second form either using a button or pressing the red X in the corner, it still adds a blank item to the list. Which is not really what I want it to do.

This is my code for the button on form1:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if there is less than items in the list, load the form
        if (addTask.Count < 10)
        {
            // New instance to load the form
            newTaskForm frm2 = new newTaskForm();
            frm2.ShowDialog();
            NewTask task = new NewTask();

                // Get the values entered by the user, eg title will be the text in textBox1 etc.
                task.title = frm2.textBox1.Text;
                task.description = frm2.textBox2.Text;
                try
                {
                    task.priority = frm2.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                task.completionDate = frm2.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
                addTask.Add(task); // Add task to the list
                listView1.Items.Add(task.title); // Display task title in the list view

                // close form
                frm2.Close();
                frm2.Dispose();

            }            

        // if there are 10 items in the list, display a message
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum number of tasks added");
        }
    }
```

Then the code on my second form where the user enters the data is this.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // check to see if all the fields have been filled in properly
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text) || comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
      {
          DialogResult = DialogResult.None; // do not send results back to main form
          MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all fields");
      }
      else
      {
          DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
      }
  }
```

I just don't understand that when I press the Red X to close the second form, it adds a blank item to the list/listview?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you doesn't check DialogResult of `ShowDialog()`:

```
newTaskForm frm2 = new newTaskForm();
if (frm2.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
   return;
NewTask task = new NewTask();
```

or

```
newTaskForm frm2 = new newTaskForm();
DialogResult res = frm2.ShowDialog();
if (res != DialogResult.OK)
   return;
NewTask task = new NewTask();
```

i suggest to make an improvement in newTaskForm:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // check to see if all the fields have been filled in properly
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text) || comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all fields");
  }
  else
  {
      DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
      Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I originally had this code in place and I just remember why I removed it, It "refreshes" my form so i have to press the close button twice before it closes it. Same with when I add a new item to the list.. Why does that cause this?

Comment: @Jamie1234, form.ShowDialog() just shows a form and makes it modal. It can't cancel closing. Do you have any handler of FormClosing event in the 2nd form? it can be a source of problem. also i would change button1_click (see update)

Comment: I added your update but still doesnt fix this weird error. No I dont have any handler of form closing event in the 2nd form, The code in OP is all the code on that form that I input myself. Like I said, if i remove that if statement then it works fine but then when I close the form, it adds an empty item to the list.

If it helps, i was trying to replicate the selected answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076562/how-to-add-items-to-a-listbox-from-a-different-form

Comment: @Jamie1234, i created a simple 2 form project, added your code but cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: Ugh, I also decided to just do 2 simples forms in a project to see where I was going wrong... I left frm2.ShowDialog(); in the code for the button on the first form and then added the if statement you told me, this is why it loaded twice -.-. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Jamie1234, I see. We didn't understand each other. I should have add  more code in my answer